# Which is exact method to install from source?

Tags: compiling, dpkg, software-installation, install-from-source

I have run (gradually) following command to install gdebi from source:

```
apt-get build-dep gdebi
apt-get source gdebi
cd gdebi-0.9.5.3
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b
```

Which gives me error (posted last few lines, ask me to post whole if needed):

```
FAIL
test_against_deb_with_conflict_against_apt (tests.test_gdebi_cli.GDebiCliTestCase) ... This package is uninstallable
Conflicts with the installed package 'apt'
ok
test_against_impossible_dep (tests.test_gdebi_cli.GDebiCliTestCase) ... This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: pkg-that-does-not-exists

ok
test_against_that_works_with_no_additonal_deps (tests.test_gdebi_cli.GDebiCliTestCase) ... ok
test_pyflakes3_clean (tests.test_pyflakes.TestPyflakesClean) ... ok
test_pyflakes_clean (tests.test_pyflakes.TestPyflakesClean) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_lintian (tests.test_gdebi_gtk_lintian.GDebiGtkTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1125, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/media/pandya/Ext4/14.04/Manual/Package-Mgt/gdebi/gdebi-0.9.5.3/tests/test_gdebi_gtk_lintian.py", line 61, in test_lintian
    self.assertMultiLineEqual(lintian_output.strip(), EXPECTED_LINTIAN_OUTPUT)
AssertionError: 'warning: the authors of lintian do not re[658 chars]us 1' != 'E: error-package: changelog-file-missing-[575 chars]us 1'
- warning: the authors of lintian do not recommend running it with root privileges!
  E: error-package: changelog-file-missing-in-native-package
  E: error-package: file-in-etc-not-marked-as-conffile etc/foo
  E: error-package: control-file-has-bad-owner postinst egon/egon != root/root
  E: error-package: no-copyright-file
  E: error-package: package-has-no-description
  E: error-package: no-maintainer-field
  W: error-package: no-section-field
  W: error-package: no-priority-field
  E: error-package: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid etc/ 1000/1000
  E: error-package: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid etc/foo 1000/1000
  W: error-package: maintainer-script-ignores-errors postinst

  Lintian finished with exit status 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 12.827s

FAILED (failures=1)
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/pandya/Ext4/14.04/Manual/Package-Mgt/gdebi/gdebi-0.9.5.3'
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

So, What is I'm missing ?

If It is not proper method, then Give me proper method to install from source.

Comment: Please post the full build log, it seems that you have at least one Lintian error. Try building with `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b` to get binaries, `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -S` for a source package

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You are attempting to build the exact same package you would install with `sudo apt-get install gdebi-gtk`. Why not just install it? The end result will be the same.

Comment: Are you building using sudo? you don't need it

Comment: let me post that as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building with `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b` to get binaries, `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -S` for a source package **without** using sudo.

Comment: Ok. build-dep is essential to build.